# Need help identifying flooring element

Tags: flooring, foundation, vinyl-flooring

I am looking to install vinyl flooring on my basement (ground level). I will be removing the existing tiles. On 2 of the walls (the ones that face the exterior) I have this mini step along the walls (see images below). It looks like continuous wall footing basement or maybe the drainage goes beneath that.

Can anyone confirm what that is and the best way to deal with it when installing new floor? It's going to be a challenge to install vinyl with that.

Any help is appreciated!

[image][image]

Answer (score 1):

I've dealt with something similar but in a laundry room and it was brick not tile. 
I did the floors and left that part alone and covered it with thin base cabinets to hold supplies.

Comment: Thanks! this is actually the laundry room as well.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like an interior drainage retrofit (or at least if you are not retrofitting, that's a poor way to do drainage.)

New floor-wise, ignore the fact that it's currently tiled "like the floor" - you don't walk on it unless you are a mouse, or a small cat. So it need not be "flooring material" nor the same as the rest of the floor. Easiest might be to leave that part as is (tiled) and let it be different from the main floor area that you do walk on. Otherwise just treat it as an awkward bit of trim, with the extra joy of "could be damp?" So wood might not be a good choice to cover it with.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I will check with my neighbor to see if this is a retrofit done by previous owner.